# HTML: How to put autoscroll in input?(last thing added has to be visible always)

Tags: javascript, html, input, scroll, focus

```js
function addHee(){
    
document.getElementById("Display2").value = document.getElementById("Display2").value + "Hee";

}

function addAaA(){
    
document.getElementById("Display2").value = document.getElementById("Display2").value + "AaA";

}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body>

<input type="text" id="Display2"name="Display2" class="displays" value="HelloMan" >

<input type="button" class="Hee" value="Hee"onClick="addHee()">
<input type="button" class="AaA" value="AaA"onClick="addAaA()">

</body>
</html>
```

When adding chars inside the input by clicking in and typing, the last entered thing is always visible.

But when adding chars by using the buttons, there is no focus on seeing what was entered last, it just always shows the front.

I want the last part entered always to be seen when adding chars with the buttons.
I couldnt find anything in the attributes of the input tag.

Answer (score 1):

**Do this:**

```
function addHee() {
  const input = document.getElementById("Display2");
  input.value = input.value + "Hee";
  input.focus();
  input.setSelectionRange(input.value.length, input.value.length);
}
```

do same for both functions.

Answer (score 0):

@Faisal Khan

I did it like this on both functions:

```
function addHee(){
let ta = document.getElementById('Display2');
document.getElementById("Display2").value = document.getElementById("Display2").value + "Hee";
ta.scrollLeft = ta.scrollWidth;
}
```

whats the difference?

Comment: There are many ways to do something, your solution is also fine.

Comment: One suggestion for you. Do this: **ta.value = ta.value + "Hee":** to shorten the code